# EVGA and NVIDIA specification difference

Tags: graphics-card, dvi

I have noticed some changes in Graphics card specification,

[EVGA GeForce GT 640 (Dual Slot)](https://www.evga.com/products/specs/gpu.aspx?pn=5abfe4f7-78a0-4cf8-98ac-d1b6578aff4c) --> `Max Digital: 2560x1600 (Dual Link DVI Only)`

[GeForce GT 640](https://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gt640/specifications) --> `Display Support : Maximum Digital Resolution   4096x2160`

I bought the EVGA card. Could anyone please clarify what is going to be my maximum resolution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You *did* read the footnote, right?

Comment: "Could anyone please clarify what is going to be my maximum resolution." - The resolution listed by EVGA.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The specifications for that EVGA card only mentions Dual-link DVI connectors, which is what is giving the limitation.

DVI is old and hasn't seen any upgrades done to the specification for many years and is limited to 2560 * 1200 (or somewhere close).

HDMI on the other hand has been progressively updated and supports 4K resolutions.

As mentioned by Daniel in the comments the Nvidia GT640 page states:

> **4096x2160 resolution supported through a single HDMI connector**. 4096x2160 resolution is not supported with two DVI connectors.

If the EVGA card has HDMI then it might support 4K, but given how old the card is it may be limited to 24/30 Hz.

Comment: Thank you very much.. I also got a post which state it can run 4k but only via mini hdmi, but for only with 30HZ.